# Azure CosmosDB, Python - Replace a document: document_link?

Tags: python, replace, azure-cosmosdb

I have a JSON document in my database that I want to modify frequently from my python program, once every 25 seconds. I know how to upload a document to the database and read a document from it, but I do not know how to modify/replace a document.

This [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-python/blob/master/pydocumentdb/document_client.py) shows the functions offered in the python module. I see the ReplaceDocument function, but it takes in a document-link. Though how can I get the document link? Where am I suppose to look for this information?

Thanks.

Comment: I found the link! I did so by querying the document in Azure and I believe the document link is the value for the key "_self"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you had resolved it. Just as summary, the code below.

```
# Query a document
query = { 'query': 'SELECT * FROM <collection name> ....'}    
docs = client.QueryDocuments(coll_link, query)
doc = list(docs)[0]

# Get the document link from attribute `_self`
doc_link = doc['_self']
# Modify the document
.....
# Replace the document via document link
client.ReplaceDocument(doc_link, doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

**April 2020**

If you are reading [MS Azure's Quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-python#clone-the-sample-application) and following [a supporting git repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-python-getting-started), note that there might be some differences.

For example,

```
from azure.cosmos import exceptions, CosmosClient, PartitionKey

endpoint = 'endpoint'
key = 'key'
db_name = 'cosmos-db-name'
container_name = 'container-name'

client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)

db = client.create_database_if_not_exists(id=db_name)
container = db.create_container_if_not_exists(id=container_name, partition_key=PartitionKey(path="/.."), offer_throughput=456

...

# Replace item
container.replace_item(doc_link, doc)
```

When it comes to `doc_link` and `doc`, in the above case, I encountered an error when I used `doc['_self']`. By using the primary key of the `doc`, the `doc` is updated.

Comment: Why is it too much to ask for Microsoft to explicitly state how to update a document.