# Update / Replace Document In CosmosDB using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to write a function that will update / replace a document on my CosmosDB database.  It's a very simple document with the key pair "name":"cer" and I want to change it to "name" : "CER" for the purpose of this thread.

I followed the example on the second answer to this thread but it does not work.

[Azure CosmosDB, Python - Replace a document: document_link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931256/azure-cosmosdb-python-replace-a-document-document-link)

Instead I get **CosmosHttpResponseError: (BadRequest) Request url is invalid.**.  The previous user commented:

*When it comes to doc_link and doc, in the above case, I encountered an error when I used doc['_self']. By using the primary key of the doc, the doc is updated.*

I suspect this is where my issue is, but I don't understand the solution (and I don't have enough credibility to comment!)

```
    client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient('database_uri', 'database_key')
    database = client.create_database_if_not_exists(id = 'database_id')

    container = database.create_container_if_not_exists(id = 'container_id', partition_key = PartitionKey(path = "/id"), offer_throughput = 400)
    
    q = 'SELECT * FROM c'
    items = list(container.query_items(
            query = q,
            enable_cross_partition_query = True
        ))

    doc = items[0]
    #there is only one document in the container for development purposes

    doc_link = doc['_self']
    doc['name'] = 'CER'
    container.replace_item(doc_link, doc)
```

Comment: check this sample https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/samples/document_management.py#L91

Comment: did it help with your ask?

Comment: Still working through the solution, needed to finish some other work this week.  Just being polite for now!

Comment: Have you tried above approch ? did it resolved your issue ?